# How can I detect if the active text editor is in preview mode (in italics) in Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I detect if the active text editor is in preview mode (in italics) in Visual Studio Code extension?

`TextDocument` doesn't have any flag for it. Only `TextDocumentShowOptions` have an option, if the next opened document will be in preview mode. But that doesn't say anything about the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.activeTab.isPreview`